# Add background image to specific tabPanel in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I use a navbarPage in my shiny application. It permits to create 2 tabpanels. I would like to custom the background of the first tabpanel ONLY.

The best option I found yet consists to create a specific style ("my_style_1") with the tag argument. And then apply it to tabpanel 1 only. My Ui.R code looks like that:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(navbarPage(

    # --- Application name
    "my application",

    # --- Creation of a style named my_style_1
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".my_style_1{ 
                background-image: url(http://papillondamour.p.a.pic.centerblog.net/fb850229.jpg );
    }"))),

    # --- Sheet number 1 wih custom style
    tabPanel( title="Page1" ,
            column(10,
                class="my_style_1",
                br(),br(),br(),h1("A piece of text"),br(),br(),br()
            )),

    # --- Sheet number 2
    tabPanel( title="Page2" ,
            column(10,
                "Another piece of text"
                ))
            ))
```

And the most basic server.R you can do:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

It almost work as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCtI9.png). But the image cover only the area of "column", it is not a real background.

If I wanted to apply the same background to every tabPanels, I could just do

```
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("body{ 
                background-image: url( http://papillondamour.p.a.pic.centerblog.net/fb850229.jpg );
    }"))),
```

And I would get this good result: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYl2w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but it could work:

- to fix the issue of having some space between the navbar and the tab content, you could add `.my_style_1 { margin-top: -20px; }` (since the navbar has a margin-bottom of 20px)
- to make the image cover the entire width, the first thing you need to do is make the image full width, so add `.my_style_1 { width: 100%; }`.  Then you need to get rid of the left and right padding of the parent container-fluid, so there are two simple options for that (possibly many more): either do `.container-fluid { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }` but then you also need to remember this will remove some padding from all other tabs , so you could manually add a padding to the other tabs. Or you could do `.my_style_1 { position: absolute; left: 0;`.  See which one works better for you

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your answer ! I use your second solution for the side padding: the one with .my_style_1 { position: absolute; left: 0;. It works awesome!!